# How to calculate the square root of a density matrix?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

We know that a quantum state can be represented by a matrix $\rho$, where $\rho$ is positive semi-definite and trace is $1$.

So, what is the definition of $\sqrt{\rho}$ and how can I calculate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the spectral theorem, every $d$-dimensional density operator $\rho$ has a unique expression in terms of its eigenvectors and eigenvalues like the following:
\begin{equation}
\rho = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i |\lambda_i\rangle \langle \lambda_i | \tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d$ are eigenvalues of $\rho$, where for simplicity we just set $\lambda_k = 0$ for $k > \text{rank}(H)$, and $\{|\lambda_1\rangle, \dots, |\lambda_d\rangle\}$ are orthonormal eigenvectors of $\rho$. Then, the definition of $\sqrt{\rho}$ is given straightforwardly as
\begin{equation}
\rho^{1/2} = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i^{1/2} |\lambda_i\rangle \langle \lambda_i | \tag{2}
\end{equation}

where $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ is real since a density matrix must be positive semidefinite (nonnegative eigenvalues) by definition. Note that this is just another way of writing a diagonalization of $\rho$, for example:
\begin{align}
\rho &= U \Lambda U^\dagger \tag{3a} \\
\rho^{1/2} &= U \Lambda^{1/2} U^\dagger \tag{3b}
\end{align}

where the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors $|\lambda_i\rangle$ and $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues of $\rho$ on its diagonal. This means that one way to calculate $\rho^{1/2}$ is by finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues $\rho$ and then reconstructing $\rho^{1/2}$ using either Eq. 2 or Eq. 3b.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!